# How to recover from crashes/hangups with intern on Selenium Grid

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, selenium-grid, intern

I am running my intern unit tests on a Selenium 2 Grid. This works fine when all tests execute normally. Also a run-time error within a test is dealt with properly: the test is reported as failed and other tests continue to execute.

Some other types of errors though are not dealt with nicely:

- A syntax error is detected by the Istanbul code coverage code and the intern-runner finishes without executing any further tests. The opened browser window on the node is not closed.
- A dependency error (reference to non existent file) causes an error in the loader. The browser windows stay open and the intern-runner keeps waiting forever.

Since I want to integrate the test execution in the build I prefer that the test finishes and releases its resources, even in case of errors.

I did look at the below sources that suggest that I should set the right timeouts, but without success:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2
https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/test-configuration/#timeouts

Here is my test setup:

- Node.js – 0.10.28
- Intern – 1.7.0
- Selenium 2 Server – 2.42.2
- ChromeDriver – 2.10
- Internet Explorer Webdriver – 2.42

I start the hub with:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role hub -timeout=20 -browserTimeout=60
```

I start a node with:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.29.1:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=internetexplorer,version=10,maxInstances=1,platform=VISTA -browser browserName=chrome,version=35,maxInstances=3,platform=VISTA
```

I then start my tests with:

```
node node_modules\intern\bin\intern-runner.js config=picard\tests\intern
```

where this is the content of the intern config file:

```
define({
    proxyPort: 9000,
    proxyUrl: 'http://192.168.29.1:9000/',

    capabilities: {
      'selenium-version': '2.42.2',
      'max-duration': 30
      //'idle-timeout': 30
    },

    environments: [
        { browserName: 'internetexplorer', version: '10', platform: 'VISTA' },
        { browserName: 'chrome', version: '35', platform: 'VISTA' }
    ],

    maxConcurrency: 3,
    useSauceConnect: false,

    webdriver: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 4444
    },

    useLoader: {
        'host-node': 'dojo/dojo',
        'host-browser': 'node_modules/dojo/dojo.js'
    },

    loader: {
      packages: [
        { name: 'cbtree', location: 'external/cbtree' },
        { name: 'dgrid', location: 'external/dgrid' },
        { name: 'put-selector', location: 'external/put-selector' },
        { name: 'xstyle', location: 'external/xstyle' }
      ]
    },

    suites: [
      'picard/tests/crashingtest,
      'picard/tests/passingtest
    ],

    functionalSuites: [ ],

    excludeInstrumentation: /^(node_modules|dojo|dojox|dijit|dgrid|xstyle|external)/
});
```

How can I configure my tests such that the intern-runner finishes execution and browser windows are closed, even if errors occurred?
Regards, Johan

Answer (score 0):

At the end of each test you'll want to call a method that handles the selenium cleanup for you. That way if there is a failure because of an error this method should still be called, and will close the browser for you.

The common name for the method that should handle cleanup is `afterEach(function ())`